# Как добавить новые и обновить существующие строки в одном запросе?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Я мало что понимаю в SQL, прошу помочь в решении задачи:
Дано:

- таблица table;
- поля id, name, email  (id - UNIQUE);
- массив данных, передаваемый из php в запрос.

Задача: написать запрос на добавление несуществующих и обновление существующих записей.

Что-то уже получилось (сам запрос):

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `email`) 
VALUES  
('1-', 'oleg', 'qqq@mail.ru'),
('2-', 'dima', 'ggg@mail.ru'),
('3-', 'petr', 'mmm@mail.ru'),
('4-', 'anna', 'nnn@mail.ru')
и так далее...
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = ????? `email` = ??????
```

Из php:

```
<?
// $arr - массив данных (порядка 10к строк формата: "('1-', 'oleg', 'qqq@mail.ru')")
$mysqli->query("
    INSERT INTO `table` (`id`, `name`, `email`) 
    VALUES ".implode(",", $arr)."
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = ????? `email` = ??????
")
?>
```

Вопрос: что надо писать после `"ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE"` для обновления существующих строк? Может, есть другие варианты решения задачи?

Comment: Уже какой раз ответ нахожу быстрее, чем подсказывают тут =(( Достаточно было написать следующие вещи: ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name=VALUES(name), email=VALUES(email)

Comment: вполне возможно что Вам помогает *[уточка](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Метод_утёнка)*